# Simplest possible python link-shortener

Tags: python-3.x, url

**I want to make the simplest possible Url shortener in Python.**

like this:

```
link = input("Type your link:")

#print output
```

**I can use for this Python libraries if needed.**

> I want the code to be as simple as possible - 10 lines maximum.

The code must be efficient.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: seems you might have ment to go to fiverr.com or somewhere cause stack overflow is not code writting service for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The simplest possible Url shortener in Python:**

```
import pyshorteners

#link = 'https://yourwebsitehere.com/'

link = input("Type your link")

print(pyshorteners.Shortener().clckru.short(link))

#output: https://clck.ru/*****
```